# Write to a file python

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
while iter < 10:
    //do some things(actual code is too long to post)
      iter += 1

    for line in code.splitlines():
        file = open("tile.txt", "w+")
        file.write(line)
        print("    "+line)
```

I have this for loop at the end and when I print out the variable "line" to the command line it works perfectly. However I want to write all the values of "line" on every iteration of the while loop into a file. My problem now is that, it only writes out the value of line on the final iteration. Any help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should opened your file in append mode. Also as a more pythonic way for dealing with files you better to use `with` statement for opening the files, which will close the file at the end of the block:

```
with open("tile.txt", "a+") as f:
    for line in code.splitlines():
        f.write(line + '\n') # Add new line at the end of each line
        print("    "+line)
```

You could also use [`file.writelines()`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/file_writelines.htm) method in order to write multiple lines in your file at once, but in that case you can still use `w+` mode.

Comment: Note that `f.write(line)` does not add a trailing newline character, so if you want everything on their own line you need to use `f.write(line + '\n')`

Answer (score 1):

you should open the file one time outside the loop:

```
file = open("tile.txt", "w+")
while iter < 10:
    //do some things(actual code is too long to post)
      iter += 1

    for line in code.splitlines():
        file.write(line)
        print("    "+line)
```

Answer (score 1):

Every time you iter through the line it overwrites the previous value you have wrote rather than adding to it:

```
file = open("tile.txt", "w+")
for line in code.splitlines():
    file.write(line)
    print("    "+line)
```

Above code should give you all the lines.It opens the file and inside the loop, all the values are written to the file. After the end of loop you should close the file to get the result.

```
file.close()
```